# How do I make a .vbs file type text

Tags: vbscript

I need to make a .vbs file that types the string "Hello World" into a program such as notepad. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the SendKeys Method. Here is the reference.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx

To open Windows Notepad you'd do a Run from Shell Command from your vbscript. You can look this up just about anywhere.

```
  Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad.exe"
  WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"

  WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World"
```

Answer (score -1):

type in notepad:

```
msgbox("Hello World")
```

then save the file as whatever you want and open. it should then work.

Comment: OP asked how to open a program and type text, not a message box